# Add prefix to special characters with Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of special characters that includes `^ $ ( ) % . [ ] * + - ?`. I want put `%` in front of this special characters in a string value.

I need this to generate a Lua script to use in Redis.

For example `Test$String?` must be change to `Test%$String%?`.

Is there any way to do this with regular expressions in C#?

Comment: Yes there is. Have you looked into `Regex.Replace` at all yet?

Comment: @codran Yes, But I want replace each character with himself and %. `Regex.Replace` can do this?

Comment: yes. Have a look at [substitutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, you just need a `Regex.Replace`:

```
var LuaEscapedString = Regex.Replace(input, @"[][$^()%.*+?-]", "%$&");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5D%5B%24%5E()%25.*%2B%3F-%5D&i=%5E%20%24%20(%20)%20%25%20.%20%5B%20%5D%20*%20%2B%20-%20%3F&r=%25%24%26)

The `[][$^()%.*+?-]` character class will match a single character, either a `]`, `[`, `$`, `^`, `(`, `)`, `%`, `.`, `*`, `+`, `?` or `-` and will reinsert it back with the `$&` backreference in the replacement pattern pre-pending with a `%` character.

A lookahead is just a redundant overhead here (or a show-off trick for your boss).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex: `([\\^$()%.\\[\\]*+\\-?])`

It will  match and capture characters inside the character class. Then you can use `$1` to reference the captured character and insert `%` before it, like so: `%$1`.

Here is an example code and [demo](https://ideone.com/mSQi0V):

```
  string input = "Test$String?";
  string pattern = "([\\^$()%.\\[\\]*+\\-?])";
  string replacement = "%$1";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
```

Comment: `\W` will match any non-word character, not just those Lua special pattern characters.

Comment: This will also replace `:` or  `;` or `{` which are not specified in the question

Comment: @lbarros when I use `%$1` the special characters replace with `%$1`. I use `%$&` instead of `%$1` and your answer work fine.

Comment: @Fred did you use a capture group? If not, i think `%$&` is the correct choice.

Comment: @lbarros you right, I forget use round bracket around my pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookaheads and replace with `%`

```
/(?=[]*+$?)[(.-])/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iZ7kA5/1)

- `(?=[]*+$?)[(.-])` Postive lookahead, checks if the character following any one from the altenation `[]`. If yes, substitutes with `%`

Comment: Why use lookaheads? A character class with `$&` as a backreference in the substitution pattern will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Even that works. Different ways  to address the same problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (?=[\^\$()\%.[]*+-\?]) regex replaced String as "%"